# Qual intent chama o compartilhamento?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber qual *intent* chama a tela abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para chamar a tela de compartilhamento, use este código

```
Intent minhaIntent = new Intent();
minhaIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
minhaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Título da ação (ex.: Compartilhar");
minhaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Sua mensagem a ser compartilhada");
minhaIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(minhaIntent);
```